# How to deal with thread synchronization in Swift

Tags: swift, multithreading

I am trying to download an image from a TCP Socket without blocking the UI on the main thread. I want the decodeImage() function to wait until downloading is finished and then set image on the UI. This code is not thread-synchronized as after a few tries it breaks.

How do I synchronize these? I watched Apple tutorials on this, but they were not very specific, without any real-life examples so I don't know how to fix this.

```
func downloadImage() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        let imageBufferSize = self.networkManager.readBufferSize()
        let bytesArray = ([UInt8])(imageBufferSize)
        let data = Data(_: bytesArray)
        let bufferSizeInteger = data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: UInt32.self)}
        let imageData = self.networkManager.readLosslessData(expectedSize: Int(bufferSizeInteger))
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.decodeImage(from: imageData)
            self.networkManager.closeSocket()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a completion handler or set the *image on the UI* after the image has been processed. Don't wait, notify.

Comment: @vadian can you be more specific? Should I get rid of threads?

Comment: It's unclear what's happening in `networkManager` with regard to threads,

Comment: @vadian networkManager is a wrapper around Kitura BlueSocket Swift Library. Is my code correct for getting image data without blocking the UI and then setting image? decode image is basically setting image like so myImage.image = UIImage(data: data)

Comment: Basically yes, but you should close the socket on the same thread you've opened it.